# Custom Directive inside a Directive Doesn't Fire in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a custom directive (to exposecertain fields), and inside that I have another directive (the drop down box for the field). It's working well on Chrome, but on IE9 it appears the `ng-show` and `ng-if` is failing to evaluate. It appears not to even enter the function I defined (I put console.log inside the isAllowed function and it appears in Chrome but not in IE9).

```
<div>
    <select id="" class="form-control" ng-model="measure" name="{{name}}">
        <option ng-if="isAllowed(name, 1)" value="1">Kilowatt Hours</option>
        <option ng-if="isAllowed(name, 2)" value="2">mmBTU</option>
        <option ng-if="isAllowed(name, 3)" value="3">Therms</option>
        <option ng-if="isAllowed(name, 4)" value="4">Decatherms</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have tried `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` and it behaves the same in IE9. It appears the `replace: true` I put on my first directive is not honoured in IE9:

[image: replacement does not appear to work]

Whereas in Chrome this is replaced as expected with surrounding `DIV` elements and my custom directives cannot be seen anywhere, which is good.

Has anyone had experience of this before? Is it something to do with having a directive inside of a directive? Seems like IE9 does the first one OK then stops.

(I wish I could drop IE9 but it's an internal app and they're still on IE9 everywhere, so I've got to make it work somehow).

PS: The aim here is to only show the options that are relevant to the given field. In this case Electricity can be measured in kWh and mmBTUs but not in Therms and Decatherms. Inside the isAllowed function is supposed to be some `switch` logic. It works fine in Chrome, just not IE9, so I might need another method as a workaround.

PPS: Angular 1.3.2. IE9 - Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 Standards.

Comment: There is a whole section in angular docs about IE support, I suggest you read it because it does specify how custom DOM nodes need to be added before hand!!!

Comment: Read it. That part is for making IE8 and below happy. IE9 doesn't seem to honour the replace but it does seem to handle the custom directives.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Isolated scope. Somehow Chrome was dealing with it OK, but IE9 was not.

In my app I have the fields I want to show to my user defined in a Partials module, but the drop-down lists is something I want to use in multiple places and they may change, so I defined them in a directive called BusinessRulesDirectives.

All I needed to do was drop in the BusinessRulesDirectives as a dependency to my Partials module and it works across both Chrome and IE9.

```
angular.module( 'ActualsPartials', [
    'BusinessRulesDirectives'
] )
```

For some reason Chrome was able to run fine with this, but IE9 did not like it:

```
angular.module( 'ActualsPartials', [] )
```

Also, no errors were being output. I just happened to double-check for isolated scope as a wild guess.

Would be interested to know why Chrome was OK but IE9 was not.